# how to get value from input html form using php

Tags: php

can someone help me how can i get the value from input name="$photo_id" as state below after submitting the form.. should be $photo_id = $_GET['photo_id'] on the next page...

```
$picture = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM gallery_photos where photo_category = ".$cid."    ");
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($picture)){ 

    $photo_id = $row2["photo_id"];
    $photo_filename = $row2["photo_filename"];
    $photo_caption = $row2["photo_caption"];
    $photo_category = $row2["photo_category"];

    echo "<ul style='float:left; list-style:none; '>";
    echo "<li><img src='".$images_dir."/tb_".$photo_filename."' border='0' alt='".$photo_caption."' /><br />";
    echo "<span><input name='$photo_id' type='text' value='$photo_caption' /></li></span>";
    echo "</ul>";
    }
```

Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty much straight forward - **HTML 101**

The only thing missing here is

```
<form> </form> tags
```

change the last 5 lines as below and it should work the way you want...

```
echo '<form method="get" action="next_file.html" >';
echo "<ul style='float:left; list-style:none; '>";
echo "<li><img src='".$images_dir."/tb_".$photo_filename."' border='0' alt='".$photo_caption."' /><br />";
echo "<span><input name='$photo_id' type='text' value='$photo_caption' /></li></span>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</form>";
}
```

Hope its helpful, 
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<form>` tag.

Split `<input name='$photo_id' type='text' value='$photo_caption' />` into 2 inputs:

```
<input name='photo_caption' type='text' value='$photo_caption' />
<input name='photo_id' type='hidden' value='$photo_id' />
```

On the next page get values with:

```
$photo_caption = $_POST['photo_caption'];
$photo_id = $_POST['photo_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can post the page you can get it from `$_POST` array other wise you have to pass in url like http://test.com?photo_id = $_GET['photo_id']; using php header function